# How to convert date to formatted string

Tags: javascript

I want to convert date from the format `2020-02-26` to `Wed 02/26`? I have tried the below code but this is not what I wanted

```
var weekday = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];
var a = new Date(order_date);
alert(weekday[a.getDay()]);
```

Comment: Note that this has nothing to do with jQuery, as that is a framework primarily for amending the DOM. For working with dates and formatting strings you just need plain JS. I've edited the question as such

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create that date format you'll need to retrieve the relevant parts of the date and piece them together in a string manually, like this:

```js
const weekday = ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"];
let d = new Date(); // order_date 

let day = weekday[d.getDay()];
let month = ('00' + (d.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
let date = ('00' + d.getDate()).slice(-2);
let output = `${day} ${month}/${date}`;

console.log(output);
```

Comment: You should append "0" if the month is a single character.

Comment: I'd be interested to hear the reason for the downvote.

Comment: I upvoted your answer. Coz I liked your way slicing strings for leading zeros. Idk, but maybe the downvoter didn't see your change.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/) if you have plenty of work to do with dates and formatting them.

```js
let now = moment('2020-02-26').format('ddd MM/DD');
console.log(now)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
```

**Format Dates**

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // February 25th 2020, 4:44:28 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Tuesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Feb 25th 20
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2020 escaped 2020
moment().format();                          // 2020-02-25T16:44:28+08:00
```

**Relative Time**

```
moment("20111031", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 8 years ago
moment("20120620", "YYYYMMDD").fromNow(); // 8 years ago
moment().startOf('day').fromNow();        // 17 hours ago
moment().endOf('day').fromNow();          // in 7 hours
moment().startOf('hour').fromNow();       // an hour ago
```

**Multiple Locale Support**

```
moment.locale();         // en
moment().format('LT');   // 4:47 PM
moment().format('LTS');  // 4:47:14 PM
moment().format('L');    // 02/25/2020
moment().format('l');    // 2/25/2020
moment().format('LL');   // February 25, 2020
moment().format('ll');   // Feb 25, 2020
moment().format('LLL');  // February 25, 2020 4:47 PM
moment().format('lll');  // Feb 25, 2020 4:47 PM
moment().format('LLLL'); // Tuesday, February 25, 2020 4:47 PM
moment().format('llll');  // Tue, Feb 25, 2020 4:47 PM
```

## UPDATE

[moment.js has come to an end](https://dev.to/mullinsmikey/farewell-moment-js-bd3). In this [official doc](https://momentjs.com/docs/), it is said that:

> **We now generally consider Moment to be a legacy project in maintenance mode. It is not dead, but it is indeed done.**

Use [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/ko/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) instead as in @Masklinn's answer

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to using moment, modern browsers have the `Intl` namespace which amongst other things has a skeleton-based [DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat).

"Skeleton-based" means instead of passing a specific format string, you specify which *fields* you want to show (and how) and it'll try to find the shortest format which satisfies the constraints in the locale you've specified:

```js
>> Intl.DateTimeFormat(undefined, {weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'}).format(new Date)
< "Tue, 25/02"
>> Intl.DateTimeFormat('de-DE', {weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'}).format(new Date)
< "Di., 25.2."
>> Intl.DateTimeFormat('ja-JP', {weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'}).format(new Date)
< "2/25(火)"
>> Intl.DateTimeFormat('fr-CA', {weekday: 'short', month: 'numeric', day: 'numeric'}).format(new Date)
< "mar. 2-25"
```